# How to show my erc20 coin custom logo everywhere?

Tags: erc-20, metamask, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, polygon

I am planning to launch my custom tokens on polygon. I want to add a logo to my coin and after a while I want to change my token logo.

I have understood that there is three ways to do that -

Manually import token and add the logo

Fill a form on ethersacan

Ask the market place to add the logo to my coin.

First approach problem - this a manual work and it only works with meta mask wallet.Besides, coin holder needs to manually impoprt it.

Second approach - not sure If I can change the logo just once or multiple time? Also is there any chance of my request getting rejected? And if they in fact, add the logo for me, Will the logo be showed from everywhere or user need s to import it anyway?

3rd approach - don’t want to list tokens right away. But if I add my logo from polyscan io then do I need to re attach logo durning listing my tokens on market place too?

I am very new to all these. Please help

Comment: The ERC-20 standard didn't include a field for logos or graphics. You have to manually reach out to the website mantainers where you wish your token logo to be displayed. That said, there are a few "centralizing" token logo repositories, such as Trust Wallet's [assets](https://github.com/trustwallet/assets).

Answer (score 1):

> Fill a form on ethereum

There is no form on Ethereum.

You need to contact individual service providers to add your logo.

For further questions, please contact any third party service provider customer support.